# how to know the history functions:config:set command

Tags: google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I want to know why the **indexflag** variable that was set disappeared.
1-1. I want to know the history of the `functions:config:set` command.
1-2. I want to know the changes to the string in firebase-tools and functions:config.

---

I ran the `firebase deploy --only functions` command yesterday.
Then there was a problem in the production environment..

During troubleshooting, I ran the firebase `functions:config:get` command and found the **indexflag** variable missing.
The value of the **indexflag** variable must be an empty string("").

I deployed it in 5 months, and my laptop changed, so I installed a new firebase-tools. I don't know the version of the firebaes-tools I used before.

I entered an empty string in the indexflag variable with the `functions:config:set` command, but when I enter the `functions:config:get` command, the variable is not entered. Eventually, I fixed the source code and solved the problem.